# To prove using Euler theorem, partial differntiation

Tags: partial-derivative, homogeneous-equation

If 
$$u=\tan^{-1}(\frac{x^3+y^3}{2x+3y})$$
then prove that
$$x^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y }+y^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=(1-4\sin^2 u)sin 2u$$

Comment: Can you calculate the partial derivatives?

Comment: i have got $$u_{xx}=-2\,{\frac {6\,{x}^{8}+18\,y{x}^{7}-6\,{y}^{3}{x}^{5}+9\,{x}^{4}{y}^{4
}-12\,{x}^{2}{y}^{6}-9\,x{y}^{7}-8\,{x}^{4}-48\,y{x}^{3}-108\,{x}^{2}{
y}^{2}-89\,{y}^{3}x-12\,{y}^{4}}{ \left( {x}^{6}+2\,{x}^{3}{y}^{3}+{y}
^{6}+4\,{x}^{2}+12\,xy+9\,{y}^{2} \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: ok Dr Sonnhard Graubner i will try thanks.